# Is there a term that describes application-wide configuration properties?

Tags: language-agnostic, domain-driven-design, naming-conventions

I have an application which has a set of collections, which contain externally configurable values.

Eg:

Currencies, TimeZones, Countries, States.

Typically, these values are displayed to a user in drop-down boxes, and are loaded from an external service, grouped by the above categories.

Is there a noun that effectively describes this 'collection of configuration value collections'?

eg:

```
interface xxxxRepository
{
     List<String> getXXXXX(String category);
}
```

What are the effective names that clearly describe this concept?

Answer (score 0):

Would "System Properties" sound generic enough ? or "MetaDataService" sound self explanatory / logical ?

Comment: Metadata might be a possibility, but at the same time, metadata is so generic (and often times misused,) that it's nearly meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

"System properties" is pretty common for application-wide configuration values but I would use that more for simple foo="bar" key/value pairs, like a database connection string for example.

It kind of seems like your example (currencies, countries, states) goes beyond what I would consider basic "configuration."  In a sense, you are defining possible enumeration values in a data-driven manner.  Maybe EnumerationRepository or EnumerationValueRepository would be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is a metadatarepository and a way to group elements by classifying them as clasifications and classification items

AppSemanticsRepostiory{

getClassification();

}

Answer (score 0):

In Ada it would be roughly analogous to `package elaboration` for generic packages... while it's not an intuitive answer, it does convey the meaning you want if you allow "package" to refer to your software[-package].